# How to improve mysql order by performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, query-performance

I have catalog with 1 million items  that have own availability by franchises. When I open a page I should show **available** items **with** images first. All tables have foreign keys and indexes, but i have an issue with order part.
Query without order executes in 0.1 ms, otherwise - up to 1 second.

I have such tables:

- departmentsFranchise (id, title) (15 rows)
- catalogCategory (id, title) (150 rows)
- catalogItem (id, title, categoryId, hasImages, enabled, deleted) (1 million rows)
- catalogVisibility (id, franchiseId, hasLocal) (15 millions rows)

full tables schema

- catalogItem
  [image]
  [image]
- catalogVisibility
  [image]

Query is

```
    SELECT i.*
      FROM catalogItem i
      LEFT 
      JOIN catalogVisibility v
        ON i.id v.itemId
       AND v.franchiseId = 3
     WHERE i.enabled = 1
       AND i.deleted = 0
       AND i.deleted = 0
       AND i.categoryId = 28
     ORDER 
        BY v.hasLocal DESC
         , i.hasImages DESC 
     LIMIT 24
```

I have this results and  explain

[image: query with order]
[image: query without order]
[image: query explain]

How can I improve my query?

I checked indexes and keys, also read this:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html
- https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/01/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-optimization/
- https://medium.com/oceanize-geeks/how-to-accelerate-mysql-query-ea375503dfe5

Comment: Left joining tables from which you select no columns makes little sense.

Comment: @Strawberry, i filtering items by these tables. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: When the two tables always have matching records, I think a straight join would be faster than a left join.

Comment: To help you we need to see your table definitions, including index definitions. Please [edit] your question to show them. Please read this, especially the section on query performance. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: `... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` is a notorious performance antipattern: it requires the server to order a whole mess of information and then discard almost all of it. Is there another way to get the result you need?

Comment: @O.Jones, i updated description  with images of table structure (thought it would be better to take screenshots from phpmyadmin, than listing text)

Comment: i understand that sorting is bad for performance, but i can't get rid of it - i need to show all items from catalog, no part of it. Some categories have images, some franchises have local storage quantity (hasLocal field),  some - have not,

Comment: ordering by columns from multiple tables, so that no single index can be used for retrieving in that order right away, also sorting by a column of the 2nd table in a LEFT OUTER join, where the outer join forces the optimizer to read the left table first -> this is never going to perform well :(

Comment: Is `catelogItem` the same as `Item`?  Are there other inconsistencies?  Please fix.

Comment: @RickJames, yes - the same, updated.

Answer (score 0):

These composite indexes may help:

```
i:  (categoryId, deleted, enabled, id)
v:  (franchiseId, itemId, hasLocal)    -- also "covering"
```

The `LIMIT 24` *cannot* be optimized.  That is, the query must first collect all the rows according to the `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE`, then sort according to `ORDER BY`, and only finally deal with the `LIMIT`.

That is caused by having 2 tables mentioned in the `ORDER BY`.

What percentage of items are "visible"?  What percentage have "images"?  If both of these are rather low, I may have a tricky speedup based on `UNION`.